# How to hide cell rows in Excel

Tags: vba

Thanks in advance for your help. I have been working on this for a few days now and have tried a few different options. What I need done is to hide specific rows of an excel sheet based on the contents of an active X dropdown. I have indexed the dropdown to a cell and every time the user changes the dropdown selection, the indexed cell contains their selection as either text or number (whichever makes it easiest to code - I've been trying both). I want to keep the code as close to how it is at the moment if possible. I'm sure there are shorter/ more convenient methods, but I just want this over. I think the issue is that when the user selects a new option from the dropdown, the macro isnt refreshing and showing ALL rows again before it begins to hide the new rows. As a result, I just end up with a whole bunch of hidden rows based on what was originally selected. I hope that makes sense.

See the code below for what I've already tried. I also tried this one too, but had the same issue (that the macro wasnt refreshing and showing ALL rows before applying another Hide function)

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
ActiveSheet.Activate
If Not Application.Intersect(Range("U13"), Range(Target.Address)) Is Nothing Then
    Select Case Target.Value
    Case Is = "Brand Health": Rows("19:39").EntireRow.Hidden = True
                                  Rows("40:60").EntireRow.Hidden = False
    Case Is = "Brand Imagery": Rows("38:60").EntireRow.Hidden = True
                                   Rows("61:81").EntireRow.Hidden = False
    Case Is = "NPS": Rows("30:82").EntireRow.Hidden = True
                         Rows("83:102").EntireRow.Hidden = False
    Case Is = "Talent": Rows("35:103").EntireRow.Hidden = True
                            Rows("104:126").EntireRow.Hidden = False
    Case Is = "Shows": Rows("37:127").EntireRow.Hidden = True
                           Rows("128:148").EntireRow.Hidden = False


    End Select

End If
End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target`enter code here` As Range)
 Sheets("Brand Tracking Dashboard").Rows("1:1000").EntireRow.Hidden = False ' Move this to the top
 If Target.Address = ("$U$13") And Target.Value = 1 Then
     Sheets("Brand Tracking Dashboard").Rows("19:39").EntireRow.Hidden = True
     Sheets("Brand Tracking Dashboard").Rows("59:1000").EntireRow.Hidden = True
 ElseIf Target.Address = ("$u$13") And Target.Value = 2 Then
    Sheets("Brand Tracking Dashboard").Rows("43:63").EntireRow.Hidden = True
    Sheets("Brand Tracking Dashboard").Rows("80:1000").EntireRow.Hidden = True
 ElseIf Target.Address = ("$u$13") And Target.Value = 3 Then
     Sheets("Brand Tracking Dashboard").Rows("32:84").EntireRow.Hidden = True
     Sheets("Brand Tracking Dashboard").Rows("101:1000").EntireRow.Hidden = True
 ElseIf Target.Address = ("$u$13") And Target.Value = 4 Then
     Sheets("Brand Tracking Dashboard").Rows("37:106").EntireRow.Hidden = True
     Sheets("Brand Tracking Dashboard").Rows("121:1000").EntireRow.Hidden = True
 ElseIf Target.Address = ("$u$13") And Target.Value = 5 Then
     Sheets("Brand Tracking Dashboard").Rows("37:129").EntireRow.Hidden = True
     Sheets("Brand Tracking Dashboard").Rows("145:1000").EntireRow.Hidden = True
     End If
End Sub
```

What should happen is that after the user makes a selection, I guess the logic should be that the sheet is told to show ALL rows before applying the hide line command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are almost there - your guess was right.  You just need to unhide all the rows before you hide the right ones based on the selection.

The first sub you posted is trying to do some unhiding, but it's only unhiding a few rows - and as you can't control what order the user selects the values in, it's probably trying to unhide the wrong ones.  (Work through what happens if a user selects "Brand Health" followed by "Shows").

Try this:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    On Error GoTo errHandler

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Set ws = Target.Worksheet
    If Not Application.Intersect(ws.Range("U13"), Range(Target.Address)) Is Nothing Then
        ws.Rows("19:148").Hidden = False                'edit this to include all the rows that could be hidden
        Select Case Range("U13").Value
            Case Is = "Brand Health"
                ws.Rows("19:39").Hidden = True
            Case Is = "Brand Imagery"
                ws.Rows("38:60").Hidden = True
            Case Is = "NPS"
                ws.Rows("30:82").Hidden = True
            Case Is = "Talent"
                ws.Rows("35:103").Hidden = True
            Case Is = "Shows"
                ws.Rows("37:127").Hidden = True
        End Select
    End If
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Exit Sub

errHandler:
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

I've made a few other improvements:

- `ActiveSheet.Activate` wasn't doing anything
- You shouldn't rely on a particular sheet being the active one - what if the user changes it halfway through your macro?  So I get the right worksheet at the start and use that throughout (make sure we are always working on the correct sheet)
- `Target` could be a range of cells; you are only interested in the value of `U13` so make that the condition for the `Select Case`
- it's neater and faster to turn off screen updating - making sure it always gets turned on afterwards (even if there's an error).
- `Rows("xx:yy")` returns whole rows so there's no need for `EntireRow`

Comment: Hi Aucuparia, 

The code is working well. The issue that I'm having now is that in cell U13, I have it referencing another cell (from another sheet), which is in turn, referencing an indexed list. I found that the sheet only changes when I manually enter the text "NPS", "Brand Health", etc, but NOT when I have a formula in it (='anothercell'!c21).

So basically, CellU13 is referencing (='Lists and Code'!C21) and that cell has =INDEX('Lists and Code'!E1:E8,'Lists and Code'!F1) in it. 

Any ideas why it doesn't like the formula in the cell and prefers typed text?

Comment: See the [documentation for Worksheet_Change](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheet.change) - "This event does not occur when cells change during a recalculation. Use the Calculate event to trap a sheet recalculation."

Comment: Note that the `Calculate` event doesn't return a target, so you either need to store the previous value of your cell, or run every time (could be slow).  but this is turning into another question...